# Monotouch crash on GetCurrentProcess()

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

When my app calls System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess(), it throws this error and crashes my app:
Unregistered icall ‘System.Diagnostics.Process:GetPid_internal()’

Is there a fix for this?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  I'm surprised that MT even allows this - I don't think iOS provides any sort of process management API's that this call could map to.

Comment: It's part of a third-party library that I'm using; I'm not exactly sure what it's doing.  If there's a fix for it, I'll ask the developer to add the fix so that I don't need to customize the third-party library whenever a new release comes out.

Comment: next obvious question - which lib is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess is not supported in MonoTouch, it should probably not have been available in the first place.

The fix is to not call Process.GetCurrentProcess (or even better: not use the Process class at all).

Comment: Ok.  Will do.  I'll ask the developer to put in preprocessor directives to effectively comment out the lines where the Process class is being called.  Thanks so much!